# public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService

Tags: asp.net, c, webforms

Hello dears Kindly ineed to handling the below code to send reset link password
to my users but iam beginner so please help me

```
public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
{
    // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Comment: It does not look like this has anything to do with [C].